# PHP Webapp With Login Issues Using IE9

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication, internet-explorer-9

I've built a PHP web application. I am getting the following feedback from some users, "I can successfully login to your website but as soon as I click a link, once logged in, I get kicked out and asked to login again... over and over again".

I am **purposefully posting without too many specifics** in an effort to avoid misdirecting any advice you can give me to solve this problem. I'm the sole back-end developer on this project and am looking to this forum for help to identify new things to test because I've been unable to make any progress regarding this problem.

Additional information:

1. Browser seems to be **IE9**
2. I'm using **PHP5.3**'s built in session functions
3. Sometimes I can reproduce the bug and sometimes I can't - That makes me think it's time oriented (but cannot say for sure).
4. I think this could be related to cookies.

Comment: You might consider using FiddlerCap (www.fiddlercap.com) to collect a traffic log from an affected customer, and use that to confirm that your cookie stopped getting sent. You can then debug why.

Comment: I am noticing a problem with IE9 where the session cookie value is different between HTTP and HTTPS.  So in other words under HTTPS the user is logged in but under HTTP they are not.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to provide more detail, like show an example of the links.

However, one thing that comes to mind immediately is a switch between `domain.com` and `www.domain.com`, or a switch between protocols. Those will render the old session cookie invalid, and force a re-login if your system is set up that way.

The best solution for this is usually forcing all requests to go either to `domain.com` or `www.domain.com`, whichever you like better.

Comment: @John I can't log in, so I can't tell whether a switch takes place. But you can. Does the host name in the address bar change after logging in?

Comment: Here's a link to my website's login page https://connect.rocware.com/?m=login

My web app automatically strips www. off the domain name and forces an HTTPS connection. I can recreate the bug when clearing all session data data (in browser and in session datastore) and accessing directly via https://connect.rocware.com/?m=login

Comment: No, the host name does not change after login.

Comment: @John okay, then that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem in IE7 and it is related to cookies' expiry time. Basically, IE deletes the cookie prior to it's expiration. Try this, before `session_start()`:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
```

It would force a "permanent" cookie do be created, which would be invalidated whenever the user closes their browser.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I just tested it by placing session_set_cookie_params(0); just before my call to session_start(); After clearing browser cookies/session data and clearing my site's session datastore, the problem still persists. I tested in IE9.